# Java's "org.json" vs C#'s "Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert"

Tags: c#, json, json.net, org.json

I'm looking for a **C# (.NET)** library that parses stringified JSON to an Object.

The problem with `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert`, to me, is that you always need a concrete type for deserialization:

```
 SomePredefinedType bla = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SomePredefinedType>(stringifiedJson);
```

So I end with many classes that I don't use anymore.
class SomePredefinedType is used **once**, in that line, and never more.

Of course the navigation is then nicer, you can call properties just like:

```
string name = bla.Name;
string age = bla.Age;
```

In **Java**, I've used org.json, in which the deserialization goes likes this:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(stringifiedJson)
```

The navigation requires that you know what the JSON structure is. But this is always a fact (otherwise how could I create the `SomePredefinedType` class?)

```
jsonObject.getString("Name");
jsonObject.getString("Age");
```

The question is:
Is there a org.json for C#? I don't like Newtonsoft.Json.
I like this way of parsing anonymously.

**Edit:**
Ok, I tend to use simplified examples in my posts, because I don't like when people post a bunch of code. I like to talk on the basis, thats why I post simple code.

Here is what I can't achieve in a simple manner, as with org.json I would:

```
        // Here not using any object, just as answers below stated I could:
        dynamic jsonProviders = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(stringifiedJson);

        foreach (dynamic jsonProvider in jsonProviders)
        {
            // Fetch provider
            SMSProvider provider = db.SMSProviders.SingleOrDefault(p => p.SMSProviderId == jsonProvider.SMSProviderId);     // What the hell do I use here? thats an error
            CheckIfExists(provider);

            provider.Order = jsonProvider.Order;
        }
```

Comment: I strongly recommend you to read the Json.NET documentation before saying you don't like it or stating that something can't be done. Some friendly advice!

Comment: There's sometimes a fine line between simplifying the problem for an example and completely changing the question. In this case, I think you crossed it: the edit really changed the question. It's now a simply solvable thing that does not require dumping Json.NET.

Comment: The problem stays the same. At the end I appreciate both your answer and @Darin Dimitrov for showing me the existance of "JObject" (and therefore JArray), it is the most likely to org.json and I dont have to deal with dynamics nor "one-time-usage classes"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update** based on your recent code, I'd say you're almost done. You could simply do this:

```
int id = jsonProvider.SMSProviderId;
SMSProvider provider = db.SMSProviders.SingleOrDefault(p => p.SMSProviderId == id);
```

Capturing the `id` this way should let EF (or whatever that is) understand exactly how to work with the value that came from the JSON.

---

Json.NET (JsonConvert) is a great library. Here are some options for doing what you want without having more classes than necessary:

```
// stringifiedJson is {"Name":"George","Age":25}
{
    dynamic deserializedDynamic = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(stringifiedJson);
    string name = deserializedDynamic.Name;
    int age = deserializedDynamic.Age;
}
{
    var deserializedAnon = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(stringifiedJson,
                             new { Name = default(string), Age = default(int) });
    string name = deserializedAnon.Name;
    int age = deserializedAnon.Age;
}
{
    var deserializedDict =
  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(stringifiedJson);
    string name = (string)deserializedDict["Name"];
    // Age is a long, two casts required
    int age = (int)(long)deserializedDict["Age"];
}
{
    var deserializedDictDyn =
  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, dynamic>>(stringifiedJson);
    string name = deserializedDictDyn["Name"];
    // Age is a long, one cast required with dynamic
    int age = (int)deserializedDictDyn["Age"];
}
{
    var deserializedJObject = JObject.Parse(stringifiedJson);
    string name = (string)deserializedJObject.GetValue("Name");
    int age = (int)deserializedJObject.GetValue("Age");
}
```

Comment: What if I have Lists? JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Person>>(stringifiedJson)

Comment: Any of these should have simple analogs for lists, e.g. the first becomes `DeserializeObject<List<dynamic>>`, in the next wrap a `new[] { ... }` around the anonymous object, and in the last use `JArray`.

Comment: well, see? not easy as org.json.

Comment: @sports I've updated my answer. I'd say it's pretty darn easy!

Comment: Taking that thing outside the LINQ operation (SingleOrDefault(x => ...)) made the trick. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

> The problem with Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert, to me, is that you
>   always need a concrete type for deserialization:

Not necessarily:

```
dynamic result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject("{\"Name\":\"John\",\"Age\":12}");
string name = result.Name;
int age = result.Age;
```

Alternatively:

```
var result = JObject.Parse("{\"Name\":\"John\",\"Age\":12}");
string name = result["Name"].Value<string>();
int age = result["Age"].Value<int>();
```

And if you don't want to use third party libraries you could achieve similar results with the built into .NET [`JavaScriptSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class:

```
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var result = (IDictionary<string, object>)serializer.DeserializeObject("{\"Name\":\"John\", \"Age\":12}");

string name = (string)result["Name"];
int age = (int)result["Age"];
```

Comment: Keep in mind that the JavascriptSerializer is horribly slow compared to Json.NET. Sometimes it *might* be important and sometimes it won't.

Comment: Yes, but if you care about performance speed you should not use JSON.NET either which is horribly slow compared to [`ServiceStack.Text`](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text)

Comment: I didn't even know about ServiceStack, looks really neat, thanks for the tip. Too bad is pretty much unaffordable for us... (We don't live on USA)

Comment: JObject is just like org.json, thanks for showing me. And its part of Newtonsoft.Json so I don't needed any new libraries!